# Oracle PL/SQL - ORA-01403 “No data found” when using “SELECT INTO”

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a pl sql code that execute three queries sequentially to determine a match level and do some logic

The issue is - when first query has no results (completely valid scenario)  I get ORA-01403  No data found.

I understand that I need to incorporate [ Exception clause when NO_DATA_FOUND ]- but how to add it and continue to the next query?

```
PL/SQL Code
     SELECT A into PARAM A FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME CONDITION;
     --  GOT ORA-01403  No data found HERE 

     MATCH_LEVEL =1;
     if A is null then 
          do some logic;
     end if


     SELECT A INTO PARAM_B FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME OTHER CONDITION
     MATCH_LEVEL =2
     if A is null then 
          do some logic 2;
     end if



     SELECT A INTO PARAM_B FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME OTHER CONDITION
     MATCH_LEVEL =3
     if A is null then 
          do some logic 3;
     end if

END    PL/SQL Code
```

Comment: Just a comment, match queries are expensive - when first query return a match - i don't need to fetch query 2 and three...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just surround your `SELECT INTO` with `begin-end;`

```
begin 

    -- your faulty statement here
Exception
When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
    -- Do what you want or nothing 
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    -- what if you get more then one row? and need specific handler for this 
When OTHERS Then
    -- do something here or nothing (optional - may happen if you have more than your SELECT INTO between 'begin' and 'Exception')

end;
```

This is like `try` block of `PL/Sql`

With this technique you can log the reason your statement failed.

Comment: If the goal of the block is to catch `NO_DATA_FOUND`, then `WHEN OTHERS` is at best pointless and at worst dangerous.

Comment: This is just to show technique. In any case, what is the danger? That some other error will be handled? What if you write it to log and then re-throw? Of course, you need to design not only your Sql Block itself but also error handling as well.

Comment: The danger is that someone reading that example will literally do nothing in that section: `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;`, which would cause the code to ignore all errors other than `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Comment: We shouldn't consider people being idiots. Most programmers know how to make a program out of example. We show the technique, they take it from there. General Patton said, "tell people what to do, not how. And you will be surprised with their ingenuity".

Comment: I'm not considering anyone an idiot. However, if someone is inexperienced enough to be searching for the solution to a `NO_DATA_FOUND` error, it's a pretty good bet that they don't know the best practices of handling errors in PL/SQL. In this case, your instruction "do something here or nothing" can be read literally, which could lead to bad code. It seemed worth a comment.

Answer (score 6):

```
Declare
--your declarations 
begin
SELECT A into PARAM A FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME CONDITION;
 --  GOT ORA-01403  No data found HERE 

 Begin

   MATCH_LEVEL =1;
   if A is null then 
        do some logic;
   end if;
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line ('Error...'); 
 END; 
 --- and son on for other blocks

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement, the PL/SQL engine assume there will be one, and only one row returned by your query. If there is no row, or more than one, an exception is raised.

FWIW, you can handle such cases without resorting on exception handling by using aggregate functions. That way, there will *always* be only one row in the result set.

*Assuming `A` can't be `NULL` in your rows:*

```
 SELECT MAX(A) into PARAM A FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME CONDITION;
 -- A would be NULL if there was *no* row. Otherwise, it is *the* value for *the* row

 MATCH_LEVEL =1;
 if A is null then 
      do some logic;
 end if
```

---

*If the `NULL` value is a possible case,* just add an extra `COUNT(*)` column:

```
 SELECT MAX(A), COUNT(*) into A, HAS_FOUND_ROW FROM SAMPLE WHERE SOME CONDITION;

 if HAS_FOUND_ROW > 0 then
     ...
 end if;
```

Comment: Definitely one of the ways to go. Only not fit when you want to know and log reason the `SELECT INTO` failed.

Comment: @T.S. I agree in the general case. But, to quote OP: _" when first query has no results (completely valid scenario) ..."_ As far as I understand, there is no need for logging the `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exceptions in that particular use case.

Comment: This is why we're here. We let OP decide what he or she needs to do

Comment: I see performance issue with this approach, 6 db fetch instead of three, The match queries are very expensive...

Answer (score 2):

Oracle will not allow you to open an implicit cursor (i.e. a `select` statement in the body of a code block) that returns no rows. You have two options here (3 really, counting @Sylvain's answer, but that is an unusual approach): use an explicit cursor or handle the error.

**Explicit Cursor**

An explicit cursor is one found in the `DECLARE` section it must be opened and fetched manually (or in a `FOR` loop). This has the added advantage that, if you parameterize the query properly, you can write it once and use it multiple times.

```
DECLARE
   a sample.a%type;
   MATCH_LEVEL number;
   cursor cur_params (some_column_value number) is
     SELECT A FROM SAMPLE WHERE some_column = some_column_value;
BEGIN
   MATCH_LEVEL := 1;
   open cur_params (match_level);
   fetch cur_params into a;
   close cur_params;
   if A is null then 
        null;  --some logic goes here
   end if;

   MATCH_LEVEL := 2;
   open cur_params (match_level);
   fetch cur_params into a;
   close cur_params;
   if A is null then 
        null;  --some logic goes here
   end if;
end;
```

**Handle the error**

If you choose to handle the error, you'll need to create a `BEGIN...END` block around the code that is going to throw the error. When disregarding an error, it's crucial that you ensure that you are only disregarding the specific error you want avoid, when generated from the specific statement you expect it from. If you simply add the `EXCEPTION` section to your existing `BEGIN...END` block, for instance, you couldn't know which statement generated it, or even if it was really the error you expected.

```
DECLARE
   a sample.a%type;
   MATCH_LEVEL number;
BEGIN
   MATCH_LEVEL := 1;
   BEGIN
      SELECT A into A FROM SAMPLE WHERE some_column = MATCH_LEVEL;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         null; --Do nothing
   END;
   if A is null then 
        null;  --some logic goes here
   end if;

   MATCH_LEVEL := 2;
   BEGIN
      SELECT A into A FROM SAMPLE WHERE some_column = MATCH_LEVEL;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         null; --Do nothing
   END;
   if A is null then 
        null;  --some logic goes here
   end if;
end;
```

While I'd discourage it, you can catch any other errors in the same exception blocks. However, by definition, those errors would be unexpected, so it would be a poor practice to discard them (you'll never know they even happened!). Generally speaking, if you use a `WHEN OTHERS` clause in your exception handling, that clause should always conclude with `RAISE;`, so that the error gets passed up to the next level and is not lost.

Comment: For the first method (Explicit Cursor) - do i need to execute all three match query at the DECLARE part? if so its impossible.

Comment: @user648026 The cursor (or the query) is not executed in `declare` block: `cursor cur_params (some_column_value number) is ...` but only when one opens it: `open cur_params (match_level)`.

Comment: still once open (to read the first match) it will execute all three, correct?

Comment: The query will be run each time it is opened, with the parameter specified. The key here is to parameterize the query, so that the parameters you provide give you different results each time it is used (this assumes that you're running similar queries each time with only the `WHERE` clause varying).